# Which is the correct sentence to use

Tags: possessives, compound-subjects

Writing personalised gift as if from baby with photos of baby + baby's dad.

Would caption read:

"Mine and my daddy's adventures" or
"Mine and daddy's adventures" or
"Me and my dad's adventures" or
"Dad and I on our adventures"

Or another alternative that isn't listed above?

Comment: You wouldn't say 'mine adventures' or 'me's adventures', so the first 3 are all incorrect. The last one is OK; other possibilities are "Dad(dy)'s and my adventures", "My adventures with Dad(dy)".

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [Mine and Riley's lives ...My and Riley's lives ...Riley and my lives?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/276367/) and ["My and her" or "mine and her"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234530/) and [My father and my birthday/My father's birthday and mine/My father's and my birthday...something else?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153696/) and possibly others. Note that not all native speakers are consistent here, particularly in *spoken* contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I would accept "Me and my daddy's adventures" with the word  *'s * understood to apply to the phrase "Me and my daddy". But it isn't great.  For one thing it places "Me" first.

Of course this is supposed to be a baby talking - and babies are very self-centred! "Me and my daddy's..." certainly sounds like children-talk.

If you want to sound more grown-up, Then "My adventures with daddy" or "Daddy's adventures with me" (depending on who you want to be the focus). "Dad and I on our adventures" is also correct (but no longer sounds childish)